# query to search user-email exists in the table

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net

I want to check user exists in table from `postgresql` database from `asp.net core(MVC)` fro login

This is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(string seller_email, string seller_password)
{
    using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    connection.Open();
    string main_query = String.Format(@"select exists(select 1 from public.""sellers"" where ""seller_email""='{0}')", seller_email);
    using var command_main = new NpgsqlCommand(main_query, connection);
    int result_main = command_main.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result_main< 0)
    {
        return View(nameof(Create));
    }
    else
    {
        return View(nameof(Sign));
    }
}
```

If the user email exists then only it should render create view.
But I want the query string to search whether user exists or not with email and give a condition to render the view
please help

Comment: If this is on a live system, it has a security hole that needs patching immediately. See https://bobby-tables.com

Comment: It is just a simple schoolproject, no security is needed

Comment: But then you might get a job, that you want to keep, and not knowing any different to "what you learned in school", you'll [cause this](https://coar.risc.anl.gov/consequences-of-sql-injection-attacks/) - better to nip it in the bud now; please look deep into the risks and don't ever write SQL that way again

Comment: Hi@jason,Do you try to use postgresql with EF core?